# Obter ID de imagem/objecto Inserido em uma TcxRichEdit

Tags: delphi, objetos

Existe alguma maneira de obter o ID de uma imagem ou objecto inserido numa RichEdit? 
Eu tentei:

```
   IDRichEdit[I]:=RichEdit.Lines.Objects[I].GetHashCode;
```

Mas dá AccessViolation.

**Update:** A imagem/objeto tem o seguinte char inerente na RichEdit: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffc/index.htm

O problema é que este mantem-se o mesmo mesmo quando inserido objetos ou imagens diferentes.

Basta que eu consiga atribuir um ID a cada um destes Chars.

Obrigado.

Comment: Uma pergunta, como que esse objeto/imagem é inserido no `RichEdit`?

Comment: Através do ClipBoard.
Clipboard.Assign(img); // img é uma Tpicture que vem de um Dialog.
Depois:
RichEdit.PasteFromClipboard;

Comment: Vc já viu esse [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318636/how-to-insert-picture-into-trichedit-in-delphi)? Como ele insere as imagens de uma forma diferente, pode facilitar vc a alcançar seu objetivo.

Comment: Obrigado! vou explorar essa possibilidade.

Comment: Essa possibilidade não é compativel com a minha versão do delphi [Delphi 2010]. 
Estou a tentar desta maneira -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989555/inserting-ole-object-to-trxrichedit